# Why is my Ternary failing to test the elements of the array?

Tags: javascript

I've been working through this function and breaking it down and testing various parts of it. It is supposed to return "Pass" if the argument is >= 89.

Everything seems to work fine until the very end of the function when I invoke `aRange` on every element of the `gradesArray` array. During my trouble shooting I found that the `sort` function is indeed returning numbers, so every element *should* be able to be tested against the `aRange` ternary. What am I missing?

```js
function testResults(finalExam, test1, test2) {
//The ternary works when tested in isolation
 function aRange(test) {
  return (Math.abs(test - 100) < 12)? "Pass" : "Fail"; 
 }
//MDN says sort turns arguments into a string and compares, yet when tested it keep everything as a number(?)
 function sortArgs(...tests) {
  return tests.sort(function(a,b) { return b - a })
 }

 let resultsArr = [];
 let gradesArray = sortArgs(finalExam, test1, test2);
 for (let grade in gradesArray) {
  resultsArr.push(aRange(grade));
 }
 return resultsArr;
}

console.log(testResults(96, 88, 92))
// should return 'Pass', 'Fail', 'Pass'
// instead returns 'Fail', 'Fail', 'Fail'
```

Comment: Try `for (let grade of gradesArray) {` (`for...in` iterates over array indices, not values).

Comment: `//MDN says sort turns arguments into a string and compares, yet when tested it keep everything as a number(?)`  - There is no `string` method associated with the `-` operator, therefore JavaScript parses both operands. For example, `"5"-"2"` still outputs `3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem in you code is [`for in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). For in iterates over indices not the values so you were passing index `0,1,2` in your range function which is why it is returning fails.

```js
console.log(testResults(96, 88, 92))

function testResults(finalExam, test1, test2) {

  function aRange(test) {
    return (Math.abs(test - 100) < 12)? "Pass" : "Fail"; 
  }
let resultsArr = [];
let gradesArray = [finalExam, test1, test2];
for(let i=0; i<gradesArray.length; i++) {
resultsArr.push(aRange(gradesArray[i]));
}
return resultsArr;
}
```

You can do it in one line.

```js
let arr = [96, 88, 92]

let op = arr.map(e=> e>=89 ? 'Pass' : 'Fails')

console.log(op)
```

Comment: If OP wanted to re-use their `aRange` function, a simple `arr.map(aRange)` would work as well.

Comment: @TylerRoper agree on first comment. Yes you're right. but i considered this line `if the argument is >= 89.` ans wrote accordingly.

Comment: Truthfully I didn't even see that line, good catch. Although I am a bit curious about why OP chose to obfuscate that formula to such an extent in their original code :)

Comment: @TylerRoper may be op got overcautious